Is the basis function of an RKHS the same as the eigenfunction of the kernel?
I am trying to derivating the reproducing property of a kernel in an RKHS. However, I meet a conflict as follows:
Consider a kernel represented as the sum of a series of basis functions: $k(x,y) = \sum^{\infty}_{i=1}\lambda_i\phi_i(x)\phi_i(y)$ where $\int k(x,y)\phi_i(x) dx = \lambda_i\phi_i(y)$ and $\int \phi_i(x)\phi_j(x)dx = 0, \forall i \ne j$.
I just wonder whether the basis function in the sum series is the same as the eigenfunction.
Because,
$$
\begin{align}
\int k(x,y) \phi_i(x) dx &= 
\int \sum^{\infty}_{j=1}\lambda_j\phi_j(x)\phi_j(y)\phi_i(x) dx \\
&=\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}\lambda_i\phi_j(y)\int \phi_j(x)\phi_i(x) dx \\
&= \lambda_i\phi_i(y)\int\phi_i(x)\phi_i(x)dx = \lambda_i\phi_i(y)
\end{align}
$$
then $\int \phi_i(x)\phi_i(x)dx=1$
However, let's consider the reproducing property of the kernel, i.e., $<k(x,y), f(x)>$. The function $f(x) = \sum^{\infty}_{i=1}a_i\phi_i(x)$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
<k(x,y), f(x)> &= 
\int \Big(\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}\lambda_i\phi_i(x)\phi_i(y)\Big) \cdot \Big(\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}a_j\phi_j(x)\Big) dx \\
&= \int \sum^{\infty}_{i=1} \lambda_i\phi_i(x)\phi_i(y)a_i\phi_i(x) dx \\
&= \sum^{\infty}_{i=1} \lambda_i a_i \phi_i(y) \int \phi_i(x)\phi_i(x) dx \\
&= \sum^{\infty}_{i=1}\lambda_ia_i\phi_i(y) \ne f(y)
\end{align}
$$
If my derivation is not wrong, I think the problem is due to the misunderstanding of the basis functions and eigenfunctions. Or maybe there are something wrong with the definition of inner product? Could you give me some suggestions or comments. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!
